# Python "MySQL Error [-1]: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters"

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am using following code to update many on for my table. However that's fine working on Windows with Python but not working on my Ubuntu machine. Update many keep saying `MySQL Error [-1]: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters`. Is there are any solution to trace what's exact causing this error?

```
def update_wifs(done_data):
    magicwallet = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="dumpass",
        password="dumuser",
        database="magicwallet"
    )
    mysql_table = "magic97mil"
    conn = magicwallet.cursor()
    
    query = ""
    values = []

    for data_dict in done_data:

        if not query:
            columns = ', '.join('`{0}`'.format(k) for k in data_dict)
            duplicates = ', '.join('{0}=VALUES({0})'.format(k) for k in data_dict)
            place_holders = ', '.join('%s'.format(k) for k in data_dict)
            query = "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})".format(mysql_table, columns, place_holders)
            query = "{0} ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {1}".format(query, duplicates)

        v = data_dict.values()
        values.append(v)

    try:
        conn.executemany(query, values)
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            print("MySQL Error [%d]: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        except IndexError:
            print("MySQL Error: %s" % str(e))

        magicwallet.rollback()
        return False

    magicwallet.commit()
    conn.close()
    magicwallet.close()

    return done_data
```

done_data coming like it. what's exact like name of the columns in my table. It's been working fine on Windows machine but keep has error on Unix

```
{'id': 73399, 'wif': 'uMx1VuwRT4cKQQyE', 'PublicAddress': 'p62GqtrDtRg', 'PublicAddressP2WPKH': 'dj3krprezquku7wkswv', 'phrase': '0075839', 'index_file': 73399, 'imported': 1}

{'id': 73400, 'wif': 'L1Ri4cv3vicfGbESct', 'PublicAddress': 'JfstH24WMHGZz63WEopk', 'PublicAddressP2WPKH': 'ffkt6xxgksktzzkq8ucydrn8ps', 'phrase': '007584', 'index_file': 73400, 'imported': 1}
```

**UPD 0. query print**

> INSERT INTO magic97mil (`id`, `wif`, `PublicAddress`,
> `PublicAddressP2WPKH`, `phrase`, `index_file`, `imported`) VALUES (%s,
> %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id),
> wif=VALUES(wif), PublicAddress=VALUES(PublicAddress),
> PublicAddressP2WPKH=VALUES(PublicAddressP2WPKH),
> phrase=VALUES(phrase), index_file=VALUES(index_file),
> imported=VALUES(imported)

**UPD 1. Full traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 313, in _batch_insert
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 659, in prepare_for_mysql
    raise ValueError("Could not process parameters")
ValueError: Could not process parameters

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/WalletMagic97mil/to_wif.py", line 76, in update_wifs
    conn.executemany(query, values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 355, in executemany
    stmt = self._batch_insert(operation, seq_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 333, in _batch_insert
    raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters
```

**UPD 2. Difference on windows and unix `values`**

So the difference of `print(values)` on Unix and Windows is:

Windows it's like:

```
[{'id': 73401, 'wif': 'iVVUsHiLPLGq3uPaPyzdQ6xFeB3', 'PublicAddress': 'nLNtv3XUiMs7f1q8vU', 'PublicAddressP2WPKH': 'epw8ae08fnjpuva7x8783', 'phrase': '0075840', 'index_file': 73401, 'imported': 1}, 

{'id': 73402, 'wif': 'i41ZqWgvoKbUjYsbA41A', 'PublicAddress': 'Vd1D2krnjMucjmLU9', 'PublicAddressP2WPKH': '20g4my4rm4xgt04ph8xcmgyk', 'phrase': '0075841', 'index_file': 73402, 'imported': 1}]
```

Unix it's like:

```
[dict_values([73101, 'bmgHbonEKw4LoUqmwSg', '7K77mEtoiH5x8FnmJi2', 'dx3pdppq0zgacldefnge8ea3', '0075576', 73101, 1]),
 
dict_values([73102, 'nojKY4pzXxJ9TeFX14vpnk', 'qkuVECaPs3WcCj', 'j5sv9q28kzaqs0m6g', '0075577', 73102, 1])]
```

I think maybe this is exact error

Comment: Print `query`. I bet the problem will be obvious. You could also post the entire stacktrace.

Comment: @MichaelRuth I just updated the question in print query. I will provide now with full traceback

Comment: @MichaelRuth Done with full traceback

Comment: That is your problem: `VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)`, `%s` is not a valid value.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Thanks but why that's been working on Windows but on Unix is not?

Comment: Are you running the same version of mysql-connector on both platforms?  (`print(mysql.connector.__version__)`).

Comment: @snakecharmerb Windows version is 8.0.26. Unix version is 8.0.26. The same

Comment: @snakecharmerb Could you check `UPD 2`. Guess I found difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one pattern for building queries:

```py
        if not query:
            columns = ', '.join('`{0}`'.format(k) for k in data_dict)
            duplicates = ', '.join('{0}=VALUES({0})'.format(k) for k in data_dict)
            place_holders = ', '.join('`{0}`'.format(k) for k in data_dict)
```

Truly, you shouldn't string-build queries. It's unsafe, error-prone, and unnecessary. A better method is to use [parameter binding](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/#h-what-is-the-parameterized-query) with prepared statements.

Comment: However still keep saying same error. But query look normal INSERT INTO magic97mil (`id`, `wif`, `PublicAddress`, `PublicAddressP2WPKH`, `phrase`, `index_file`, `imported`) VALUES (`id`, `wif`, `PublicAddress`, `PublicAddressP2WPKH`, `phrase`, `index_file`, `imported`) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id), wif=VALUES(wif), PublicAddress=VALUES(PublicAddress), PublicAddressP2WPKH=VALUES(PublicAddressP2WPKH), phrase=VALUES(phrase), index_file=VALUES(index_file), imported=VALUES(imported)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why. But I replace following code like it:

```
v = list(data_dict.values())
values.append(v)
```

And it's begun working fine for me

Comment: In Python2, `dict.values()` returns a `list`.  In Python3, `dict.values()` returns a [view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).  So it seems that on Windows you are using Python2, but on Unix Python3.